# Skrollr: How to animate keyframe differently based on direction of scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, direction, skrollr

I'm using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for scroll based animation. I'm having difficulty with displaying an animation at a certain keyframe differently based off the user scrolling up vs down, but everything else works fine. Here's the relevant code (the end part, data-emit-events, is the crux of the matter) :

```
<div class="introTransition" data-0-start="width:30%; left:100%;" 
data-125="width:30%; left:60%;" data-250="width:30%; left:20%; opacity:1; 
display:block;" data-375="width:30%; left:-20%; opacity:1; display:block;" 
data-500="width:30%; opacity:0; display:none;" data-emit-events>
</div>
```

and the script call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $trans = $('.introTransition');
    skrollr.init({forceHeight:false, smoothScrolling:true,
    keyframe: function($trans, data125, up) { //element, name, direction
        //name will be one of data500, dataTopBottom, data_offsetCenter
        console.log('yesssss');
        $('.introTransition').css({'height':'50%'});
    }
    });
    </script>
```

I don't know why this isn't working. Am I just reading the docs wrong? [image: Skrollr docs excerpt]

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Here's a [link](http://jsbin.com/magur/1/edit?html,output) to a JSbin demonstrating my problem.

ANSWER: See Prinzhorn's JSbin [here](http://jsbin.com/tugileza/1/edit) for a working solution. I had done goofed the keyframe syntax significantly.

Comment: It would be best if you could post a demo page, e.g. on jsbin.com

Comment: Here's a link to a JSbin: http://jsbin.com/magur/1/edit?html,output
I want $trans to be red only at keyframe 125 (data-125) when scrolling up.

Comment: What does "only **at** keyframe 125" mean? Do you want it to flash red real quick while the user scrolls?

Comment: I should have been more clear: I need $trans to be red between data-125 and data-250, (so it will turn red at data-125, and then stop being red at data-250) but only when scrolling up. The "but only when scrolling up" part is where the problem is.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tugileza/1/edit

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much! Wonderful plugin by the way.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// first get the element that you want to listen to its keyframe event
var $trans = $('.introTransition');

skrollr.init({forceHeight:false, smoothScrolling:true,
keyframe: function(element, name, direction) { //element, name, direction
    //name will be one of data500, dataTopBottom, data_offsetCenter
    // see the first criteria, we check if element match the element we selected above
    if(element == $trans && name == "data125" && direction == "up")
    {
        console.log('yesssss');
        $('.introTransition').css({'height':'50%'});
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is always good to have a description to accompany code. You can edit your answer to include one.